# Setting background colour of empty table view space

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to set the background colour for the empty space in my `UITableViewController`, however I am running into issues. I can't just set the background colour in the storyboard because the colour has opacity. When I set it like this, the colour ends up being very dark.

I have also tried this:

```
    let backgroundTableView = UIView()
    backgroundTableView.frame = view.frame
    backgroundTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 117, green: 143, blue: 182, alpha: 15)
    self.tableView.backgroundView = backgroundTableView
```

but this does nothing.

Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  var frame_ = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.tableView.backgroundView!.frame.width, height: self.tableView.backgroundView!.frame.height)
    var SubView = UIView(frame: frame_ )
      SubView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 117/255.0, green: 143/255.0, blue: 182/255.0, alpha: 15/255.0)
      self.tableView.backgroundView = SubView
```

Comment: That gives me `unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value` on the first line unfortunately.

Comment: Try to take out the self

Comment: Use it let to unwrapped the nil

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
backgroundTableView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 117/255.0, green: 143/255.0, blue: 182/255.0, alpha: 15)
```